# Making Google API calls to only one user

Tags: node.js, express, google-calendar-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm writing an in-house app and we're using some of the Google API's in Express/node.

Since I'm only going to use one google account (an email I made just for this purpose), what's the best authentication configuration to use?

Answer (score 0):

It's a [service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount).

From the Google Developer Console create a service account for your app, the use the API key generated in your app.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer your own question (generally a good thing) but in this case, the answer is "if you're acting as a user, use a user account. If you're acting as a service, use a service account" which is stated pretty explicitly in the documentation. You're also funnelled through creating an appropriate account when accessing the Google Developer Console which is how you get started with all the Google Apis. I'm not sure how much value this Q&A adds...